# Searching within a String Array, code wants Boolean?

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

So my code is supposed to search within a String Array for a name. So "mit" would find "Smith", I am almost there but there is a problem within my method. Inside the `for` loop searching for names, there's an error telling me I need a Boolean and I'm using a String. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
public static void Search(String[] arr, String find) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (arr[i].toLowerCase()).contains(find.toLowerCase()) {
             System.out.println(String.format("found name: %s", arr[i]));
             return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Name not found!");
}
```

The error is in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this:

```
if (arr[i].toLowerCase()).contains(find.toLowerCase())
```

Count the brackets... you're closing the `if` condition immediately after the first `toLowerCase()`, and *not* closing it after the `contains` call. You want:

```
if (arr[i].toLowerCase().contains(find.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: One `(` is missing! A rare oversight by Jon Skeet :)

Comment: @KingsIndian That's not an oversight, he just changed java

Comment: Users don't mark Jon Skeet's answers as accepted. The universe accepts them out of a sense of truth and justice.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
if ( arr[i].toLowerCase().contains(find.toLowerCase()))
```

You are closing the parenthesis too early so inside the if you have a string instead of a boolean.